# How to fetch all fields of a document in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I used this code (in Dart) to fetch all fields from a Firebase Firestore document and convert to a list of objects:

```
final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await firestore.collection('configs').doc('stores').get();

    _allStores = documentSnapshot.data().values
        .map((store) => Store.fromMap(store))
        .toList();
```

But I'm currently using cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0, and `.values` in `documentSnapshot.data().values`, is no longer supported. How can I fetch all fields of a document in Firestore?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from this [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes), you get a `Map<String, dynamic>` with all the values directly from `data()`. So:

```
Map<String, dynamic> values = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

In cases where you *must* specify the type, that'd (according to the documentation on [migrating to 2.0](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration)) be a `DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

Comment: How do I convert `Map<String, dynamic>` into a list of objects, just like it was in the previous code?

Comment: Data has always been exposed as a `Map<String, dynamic>` as far as I know, because it's a set of name-value pairs.